# iOS 9 UIButton Initialization

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ios9

I am trying to initialize a `UIButton` programmatically but see one of these errors:

> buttonWithType is unavailable: use object construction UIButton(type:)

or

> error: incorrect argument label in call (have 'buttonWithType:', expected 'type:')

```
  for char in keys {
        let btn: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)
        btn.setTitle(char, forState: .Normal)
        btn.sizeToFit()
        btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)

        btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: (216/360.0), saturation: 0.1, brightness: 0.81, alpha: 1)//
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), forState: .Normal)

        btn.setContentHuggingPriority(1000, forAxis: .Horizontal)
        btn.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, forAxis: .Horizontal)

        btn.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handleBtnPress:"), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        self.addSubview(btn)
    }
```

[image: error]

Comment: `UIButton(type: ...)`?

Comment: I do not understand you

Comment: See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The convenience initializer for `UIButton` has changed.

> `convenience init(type buttonType: UIButtonType)`

Swift 3:

```
let btn = UIButton(type: .system) // note the lower case s
```

Swift 2.x:

```
let btn = UIButton(type: .System)
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10 Xcode 8.....

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .system) // note the lower case s
    button.setTitle("Dismiss", for: UIControlState())
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let buttonWidth: CGFloat = alertWidth/2
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 40
    button.frame = CGRect(x: alertView.center.x - buttonWidth/2, y: alertView.center.y - buttonHeight/2, width: buttonWidth, height: buttonHeight)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ExampleIIIViewController.dismissAlert), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    alertView.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score -2):

In iOS 9 **convenience init has been changed** for buttonWithType. You cannot use

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System)
```

instead use

```
 let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System)
```

Below is syntax :

[image: Screenshot]